# Why the time complexity of bellman equation is n^3 for the direct solution?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

For matrix form of bellman equation there is a direct solution. But I dont understand why the computational complexity for this form is n^3. I will be very appreciated if anyone can explain. thx

Answer (score 2):

The Bellman equation of the value function in vector form can be written as

**V** = **R** + γ**PV**

Where

- **V** is a column vector representing the value function for each state (1..n)
- **R** is a column vector representing the immediate reward after exiting a particular state
- γ (gamma) is the discount factor
- **P** is an nxn transition matrix (All the places we may end up)

Because the Bellman equation is a linear equation we can solve it directly. We can solve for **V** by rearranging the equation like this.

**V** - γ**PV** = **R**

(**I** - γ**P**) **V** = **R**

**V** = **R** (**I** - γ**P**)^-1

Basically, due to the fact that you need to perform matrix inversion to solve for **V**, which is O(n^3) complexity using the standard [Gauss-Jordan algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency)